# Remote PowerShell for Sharepoint: Invoke-Command won't run Add-PSSnapin on remote server

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I'm writing a powershell script to perform some archiving functions on our sharepoint server.  I'm testing this script with a server hosting Sharepoint and a remote computer running powershell.  The functional portion of the script runs as designed from the server side, I'm just trying to modify it to run remotely. I've enabled WSmanCredSSP on both server and client with their respective settings as well as enabled all other settings for communication between the two.  Running the script, I can successfully start a PSSession using the credentials, but I am unable to run any sharepoint related functions from the local computer.  I am using Invoke-Command to run "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell" as well as some other code to collect site info.  Here's a segment of my code that represents my problem:

```
param(
[string]$sitePath = "http://siteurl",
[string]$webPath = "",
[string]$sourceList = "",
)

$session = New-PSSession -Computername 192.168.5.139 -authentication -Credential CompName\admin
Invoke-Command -session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Host $Host.name
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
    Start-SPAssignment -Global
    Write-Host "What is the name of the source list? " -NoNewLine
    $sourceList = Read-Host
    $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($sitePath)
    $web = $site.AllWebs | where { $_.name -eq $webPath}
}
```

The code runs until the line "$site = new-object..." where it generates this error:
"Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite."
I'm assuming this means that the sharepoint assembly is not being initiated for the snapin command, though I can't figure out why, as it runs just fine from the server side. $Host.name inside of Invoke-command outputs "ServerRemoteHost" which I believe indicates that it is working to that point. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I'm certainly no expert in powershell or sharepoint, but I need to make this work. Thanks.

UPDATE: I realized that $sitePath and $webPath needed to be created within the Invoke-command block, after doing this, the constructor error no longer occurs but a new one is generated on the line "$web = $site.Allwebs...": "The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the collection: "Access is denied.""  Any ideas on why permissions not be granted?

Comment: SOLUTION:  Two things needed to be done to solve my issue.  First off, all variables must be declared within Invoke-Command as these are not passed between computers. Essentially all I did was place the entire script within the Invoke-Command script-block with exception of the enter and exit-PSSession lines.  Next, to fix the "Access is Denied" errors I was receiving, I added two lines:

    $siteID = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://MySharepointSiteUrl
    $siteID.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("ServerDomain\username")

Script ran as designed after this.

Comment: If you need to pass variables from the local computer to the remote computer, you can add a Param ( $var1, $var2, ...) style block to your Invoke-Command ScriptBlock, then use the -ArgumentList parameter and an array of the parameters to pass.

Comment: eg:
Invoke-Command -session $session -ScriptBlock {
 Param ( $sitePath, $webPath); <#...#> } -ArgumentList $sitePath,$webPath